# How to select rows that start with specified letter in Flutter using Moor

Tags: sqlite, flutter, sqflite, flutter-moor

I have a table called `Items` with a column called `Name`. How can I do a query to get only items that start with a certain letter?

For example if I wanted all items that start with words R2. I tried the code below but its wrong :

```
 Future<List<Item>> getFilteredItems() => (select(items)..where((t) => t.Name.like('R2'))).get();
```

What is the proper to write the query?

Comment: Did you try using SQLite wildcards as described for `like`? E.g. https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-like/ => `'R2%'`. If yes, what keeps you from using it?

Comment: @Yunnosch Oh yes I missed that. Thanks I've used wildcards and works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All aspects of your questions beyond simple SQLite are beyond my knowledge.
But turns out (confirmed by OP) that my first doubt solved the problem:

Use `'R2%'` instead of `'R2'`. I.e. use the proper SQLite wildcard.